# Unmet Peer dependency issue when running node in docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, npm

I'm using `node-pg-migrate` which has a peer dependency on `pg`. a snippet from the libraries `package.json` file

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "pg": "^4.3.0"
  },
```

I'm trying to run the application in docker with the below DockerFile

```
FROM node:latest

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Copy .env file


# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN cat package.json

EXPOSE 8000
```

I get the below error after the libraries are installed

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
npm WARN node-pg-migrate@0.0.10 requires a peer of pg@^4.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN 42EXP@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN 42EXP@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm info ok
```

Whats wierd is that i'm using another library `pg-promise` which also has a dependency on `pg`. But it doesnt seem to cause the error

this is a snippet of `pg-promise` package.json file

```
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "5.1",
    "spex": "1.x",
    "pg-minify": "0.3",
    "manakin": "^0.4.6"
  },
```

As you can see , `pg-promise` has `pg` as its dependency while `node-pg-migrate` seems to specify `pg` as its peer dependency.

The thing is , i can see that pg actually gets installed via `pg-promise`

This is a snapshot of what npm outputs after it installs all the libraries

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY pg@6.1.0
+-- pg-promise@5.3.2
| +-- manakin@0.4.6
| +-- pg@5.1.0
| | `-- pgpass@0.0.6
| +-- pg-minify@0.3.3
| `-- spex@1.0.17
```

So pg does get installed .. but it looks like `node-pg-migrate` still cannot find the library.

```
node             | > 42EXP@1.0.0 migrate /usr/src/app
node             | > pg-migrate up
node             |
node             | module.js:457
node             |     throw err;
node             |     ^
node             |
node             | Error: Cannot find module 'pg'
node             |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
node             |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
node             |     at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
node             |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
node             |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-pg-migrate/lib/db.js:5:10)
node             |     at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
node             |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
node             |     at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
node             |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
node             |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
```

I have tried globally installing the `pg-migrate` library as well as installing `pg` as a standalone library altogether by changing the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm cache clean
RUN npm install -g node-pg-migrate
RUN npm install --save pg
RUN npm install

# Copy .env file


# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN cat package.json

EXPOSE 8000
```

but i still seem to be getting the same error regardless of what i do. Is there anything else i can try?

Answer (score 1):

I added `"pg":"^4.3.0"` to package.json and it seems to be working now. It looks like `pg-migrate` looks for a very specific version of `pg`